# Convert true and false in Coffeescript to 1 and -1 respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, code-golf

```
if x < change.pageX # pageX is cross-browser normalized by jQuery
            val = Number(elem.text())
            return elem.text(o.max) if val + o.step > o.max
            return elem.text(o.min) if val + o.step < o.min
            elem.text(val + o.step)
else x > change.pageX
  # same thing, only - instead of +
```

(Coffee Script, but you get the idea). I'm looking for a trick to take a boolean and convert it to either 1 (true) or -1 (false). that way I can do `val + converted_bool * o.step` and save an if.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this...

```
+x||-1
```

---

- If `x===true`, the `+x` is `1`, and the `-1` is short-circuited.
- If `x===false`, the `+x` is `0`, and the `-1` is returned.

---

*Here's another way...*

```
[-1,1][+x]
```

- If `x===true`, `[+x]` will grab index `1` of the Array.
- If `x===false`, `[+x]` will grab index `0` of the Array.

Comment: Is the second way pure JS? or involves coffescript?

Comment: @ajax333221: They're both pure JS. This `[-1,1]` creates an array with two members, and `+x` converts the `x` boolean to `0` (if false) or `1` (if true). Therefore `[+x]` is grabbing either index `0` or `1` of the `[-1,1]` Array.

Comment: ...but it's also valid CoffeeScript syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
if true then 1 else -1
1
if false then 1 else -1
-1
```

Comment: In CoffeeScript `false ? 1 : -1` returns `false`.

Comment: The question said JavaScript.

Comment: Ternaries in CoffeeScript simply use `if`/`then`/`else`: `if true then 1 else -1`.

Comment: @Trevor Burnham — I said "said" not "says", the question title has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

I smth like that will work:

```
b2i = (x) -> if x then 1 else -1
b2i(true)  # => 1
b2i(false) # => -1
```

That function definition will result into that (not very exciting) JavaScript:

```
var b2i;

b2i = function(x) {
  if (x) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
};
```

**Note** that CoffeeScript `?` is existential operator so

```
x ? 1 : -1
```

will convert to smth a bit unexpected as

```
if (typeof x !== "undefined" && x !== null) {
  x;
} else {
  ({ 1: -1 });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

(~true)+3 and (~false) will give you 1 and negative one :)

Comment: You need an additional conditional to pick which expression to use.

Comment: well played sir. well played.

Comment: i use this when doing indexOf ... if(~"xyz".indexOf("y"))

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for anything beyond this plain javscript:

```
boolVal ? 1 : -1
```

Or, in function form:

```
function convertBool(boolVal) {
    return(boolVal ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Straight math involving boolean values converts `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`:

```
var x,y;
x = false;
y = 2;
alert(y + x);  // alerts 2

x = true;
y = 2;
alert(y + x);  // alerts 3
```

If performance is of interest, here's a [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/convert-bool-to-1-and-1) of four of the methods offered as answers here.  In Chrome, the ternary solution is more than 7x faster.

Comment: Added jsperf test to my answer that compares the performance of a number of the offered solutions: http://jsperf.com/convert-bool-to-1-and-1.

Answer (score 0):

Ah Ha!

`2 * (!!expression) - 1`

Comment: Why would you use this instead of the ternary examples above?

Comment: If `expression` can be guaranteed to be a Boolean, you don't need the `!!` cast. Just go: `2 * expression - 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can also type javascript inside coffeescript:

```
foo = `bar ? 1 : -1`
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use pure coffeescript?  `foo = if bar then 1 else -1`

Comment: The question is tagged 'code golf' suggesting a compact solution was of interest.